# Jenkins slave error reading zip file

Tags: jenkins

We are running Jenkins ver (1.614) on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64) and am trying to diagnose a failure on one of our slave nodes.

The exception that I am seeing is the following;

My question is how to diagnose what JAR file it was trying to process upon failure?

```
272 slave setup done.
273 Slave successfully connected and online
274 log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.BooleanConverter).
275 log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
276 Sep 25, 2015 12:22:07 PM hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread run
277 SEVERE: Unexpected error in channel channel
278 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/remoting/Channel$OrderlyShutdown
279         at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
280         at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2308)
281         at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1897)
282         at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getDeclaredSUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:1639)
283         at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$700(ObjectStreamClass.java:69)
284         at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:467)
285         at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:455)
286         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
287         at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:455)
288         at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:352)
289         at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:589)
290         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1601)
291         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1514)
292         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1750)
293         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
294         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
295         at hudson.remoting.Command.readFrom(Command.java:92)
296         at hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:34)
297         at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:48)
298 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.remoting.Channel$OrderlyShutdown
299         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
300         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
301         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
302         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
303         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
304         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
305         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
306         ... 19 more
307 Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error reading zip file
308         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
309         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:56)
310         at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:677)
311         at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:413)
312         at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
313         at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195)
314         at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:380)
315         at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:178)
316         at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:165)
317         at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getManifest(URLClassPath.java:756)
318         at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:416)
319         at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
320         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
321         ... 25 more
322 
323 channel stopped
324 Exception in thread "Channel reader thread: channel" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/remoting/Channel$OrderlyShutdown
325         at hudson.remoting.Channel.terminate(Channel.java:831)
326         at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:76)
327 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.remoting.Channel$OrderlyShutdown
328         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
329         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
330         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
331         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
332         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
333         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
334         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
335         ... 2 more
336 Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error reading zip file
337         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
338         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:56)
339         at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:677)
340         at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:413)
341         at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
342         at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195)
343         at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:380)
344         at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:178)
345         at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:165)
346         at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getManifest(URLClassPath.java:756)
347         at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:416)
348         at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
349         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
350         ... 8 more
351 Slave JVM has terminated. Exit code=0
352 ERROR: Connection terminated
353 ^[[8mha:AAAAWB+LCAAAAAAAAP9b85aBtbiIQSmjNKU4P08vOT+vOD8nVc8DzHWtSE4tKMnMz/PLL0ldFVf2c+b/lb5MDAwVRQxSaBqcITRIIQMEMIIUFgAAckCEiWAAAAA=^[[0mjava.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
354         at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:50)
355 Caused by: java.io.EOFException
356         at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2325)
357         at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2794)
358         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:801)
359         at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
360         at hudson.remoting.ObjectInputStreamEx.<init>(ObjectInputStreamEx.java:40)
361         at hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:34)
362         at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:48)
363 [09/25/15 12:42:32] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

Comment: Do the Jenkins server logs provide any other stack traces?  Go to Manage Jenkins -> System Log -> All Jenkins Logs